# Skip / break Iron python program in middle

Tags: ironpython

Is there any alternate for 'goto' command in IronPython?
I tried using sys.exit(). but it gives system exit exception.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to escape for certain exceptions or something?  Why don't you just encapsulate the relevant script in a "while-try" loop?  If you're just trying to escape on certain conditions, creative use of If clauses and while loops can still be the solution.

```
something = True
While(something):
    try:
        doing things
    except as e:
        print e
        something = False
```

In addition, break can break out of a loop in the middle of flow.  It's not the most graceful, but it gets the job done as long as you handle any infinite loops.

```
While(True):
    do things
    if(condition):
        break
    else:
         print "Condition not true"
    do more things
    break
```